# Echo Shortcode displaying URL instead of executing shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, advanced-custom-fields

I am using the repeater field of the Advanced Custom Fields plugin for WordPress to display song names and where relevant, offer a sample to play using the Compact Audio plugin.

I am using the `echo shortcode` function and this works to an extent - however, it's not actually executing the shortcode and is instead showing the file URL (which is the value of the field "ceremonial_sample"). I have used this on other sites (albeit not within the repeater field - that's the only difference along with the field names). Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Here is the page where I'm experiencing the problem: http://jessicaburton.co.uk/jbwp/weddings/repertoire/

Code below:

```
<?php

// check if the repeater field has rows of data
if( have_rows('ceremonial') ):

    // loop through the rows of data
    while ( have_rows('ceremonial') ) : the_row();

        // display a sub field value
        echo '<div class="song">';

    the_sub_field('ceremonial_song');

        echo '<div class="sample">';


if(the_sub_field('ceremonial_sample') ):
echo
do_shortcode( '[sc_embed_player fileurl="'.the_sub_field( 'ceremonial_sample' ).'"]' );
endif;


    echo '</div>';

    echo '</div>';

    endwhile;

else :

    // no rows found

endif;

?>
```

Comment: how about assigning the the_sub_field('ceremonial_sample'); to a variable instead of doing the if(the_sub_field ie: $sample = the_sub_field( 'ceremonial_sample' ); then do a check on that, and use that variable in the shortcode, I think the field must have a print or echo which is just echo'ing it to the page,

Comment: Sincere question: *what's wrong* with [reading the documentation?](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/functions/the_sub_field/)

Comment: I _did_ read the documentation but it didn't have an answer for a query as specific as mine. I always try and solve problems myself and read the documentation before asking questions, but in this case I couldn't find the answer.